# .Sort() function not sorting data in array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of grades in mongoose, with students inside each grade nested in that array. I've been trying to sort the number of laps each student has inside of one array, but the sort function isn't sorting them; it leaves them in the formation they were in.

```js
[
 name: 'Grade A',
  user: 625b2ea7a921450275bd9500,
  students: [
    {
      _id: 625d8f55a856e935cebe070a,
      name: 'OB',
      laps: 18,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:28:39.734Z,
      avgSpeed: 307.32371093750004,
      topSpeed: 663.36
    },
    {
      _id: 625d8f5ca856e935cebe070b,
      name: 'CB',
      laps: 7,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:20:33.618Z,
      topSpeed: 9562.13,
      avgSpeed: 944.2103125
    },
    {
      _id: 625d8f62a856e935cebe070c,
      name: 'CC',
      laps: 5,
      time: 2022-05-14T19:59:31.637Z,
      avgSpeed: 3.245,
      topSpeed: 6.49
    },
    {
      _id: 625d8f67a856e935cebe070d,
      name: 'JC',
      laps: 6,
      time: 2022-05-14T19:57:05.646Z,
      avgSpeed: 516.751875,
      topSpeed: 7128.13
    },
    {
      _id: 625d8f6aa856e935cebe070e,
      name: 'EE',
      laps: 5,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:18:13.486Z,
      avgSpeed: 2904.3375,
      topSpeed: 10317.03
    },
    {
      _id: 625d8f70a856e935cebe070f,
      name: 'LF',
      laps: 3,
      time: 2022-05-14T19:09:00.683Z
    },
    { _id: 625d8f78a856e935cebe0710, name: 'RH', laps: 2 },
    {
      _id: 625d8f7ea856e935cebe0711,
      name: 'AH',
      laps: 22,
      time: 2022-05-14T19:06:35.126Z
    },
    { _id: 625d901b6922d33754e48622, name: 'SM' },
    { _id: 625d90206922d33754e48623, name: 'CP' },
    { _id: 625d90256922d33754e48624, name: 'SS' },
    {
      _id: 625d902b6922d33754e48625,
      name: 'NT',
      laps: 3,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:26:21.236Z,
      avgSpeed: 582.14,
      topSpeed: 605.01
    },
    {
      _id: 625d902f6922d33754e48626,
      name: 'IZ',
      laps: 3,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:22:45.552Z,
      topSpeed: 9117.38,
      avgSpeed: 2569.3199999999997
    },
    {
      _id: 6261d505122d0a073be3fc73,
      name: 'Mr. T',
      laps: 59,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:14:43.743Z,
      topSpeed: 997.58,
      avgSpeed: 102.66416015625
    }
  ],
  topSpeed: [],
  topLaps: [],
  createdAt: 2022-04-18T16:18:10.578Z,
  __v: 0
},
 {
    _id: 625d88094d09ed2e5090f91b,
    name: 'Grade B',
    user: 625b2ea7a921450275bd9500,
    students: [
      {
      _id: 625d8f55a856e935cebe070a,
      name: 'j',
      laps: 18,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:28:39.734Z,
      avgSpeed: 307.32371093750004,
      topSpeed: 663.36
    },
    {
      _id: 625d8f5ca856e935cebe070b,
      name: 'i',
      laps: 7,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:20:33.618Z,
      topSpeed: 9562.13,
      avgSpeed: 944.2103125
    },
    {
      _id: 625d8f62a856e935cebe070c,
      name: 'h',
      laps: 5,
      time: 2022-05-14T19:59:31.637Z,
      avgSpeed: 3.245,
      topSpeed: 6.49
    },
    {
      _id: 625d8f67a856e935cebe070d,
      name: 'h',
      laps: 6,
      time: 2022-05-14T19:57:05.646Z,
      avgSpeed: 516.751875,
      topSpeed: 7128.13
    },
    {
      _id: 625d8f6aa856e935cebe070e,
      name: 'j',
      laps: 5,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:18:13.486Z,
      avgSpeed: 2904.3375,
      topSpeed: 10317.03
    },
    {
      _id: 625d8f70a856e935cebe070f,
      name: 'iF',
      laps: 3,
      time: 2022-05-14T19:09:00.683Z
    },
    { _id: 625d8f78a856e935cebe0710, name: 'H', laps: 2 },
    {
      _id: 625d8f7ea856e935cebe0711,
      name: 'g',
      laps: 22,
      time: 2022-05-14T19:06:35.126Z
    },
    { _id: 625d901b6922d33754e48622, name: 'd' },
    { _id: 625d90206922d33754e48623, name: 'f' },
    { _id: 625d90256922d33754e48624, name: 'e' },
    {
      _id: 625d902b6922d33754e48625,
      name: 'c',
      laps: 3,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:26:21.236Z,
      avgSpeed: 582.14,
      topSpeed: 605.01
    },
    {
      _id: 625d902f6922d33754e48626,
      name: 'b',
      laps: 3,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:22:45.552Z,
      topSpeed: 9117.38,
      avgSpeed: 2569.3199999999997
    },
    {
      _id: 6261d505122d0a073be3fc73,
      name: 'a',
      laps: 59,
      time: 2022-05-15T15:14:43.743Z,
      topSpeed: 997.58,
      avgSpeed: 102.66416015625
    }
    ],
    topSpeed: [],
    topLaps: [],
    createdAt: 2022-04-18T15:47:21.875Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

I've tried using something like this to sort, but it doesn't return the items in a sorted order.

```js
let sorted = await Sensor.findById(req.params.id).sort({ laps: -1 }).exec();

    console.log("sorted", sorted);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Again, I'm only trying to sort the students by laps in a certain grade, not all of the students from all classes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```js
let sorted = await Sensor.findById(req.params.id).sort({
  "students.laps": -1
}).exec();

console.log("sorted", sorted);
}
catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: It's still not sorting them; they are showing up in the exact same order as they were before.